# Validação CPF Jquery JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá.

Estou tentando fazer uma validação para cpf, este código é em Jquery, e sem utilizar onclick ou algo similar nos input, precisa pegar apenas o ID do input no form.

Segue o código:

```
jQuery(function(a) {
    var b = {
        init: function() {
            "0" === wcbcf_public_params.sort_state_country && a(document.body).on("country_to_state_changing", this.country_to_state_changing), "0" !== wcbcf_public_params.person_type && this.person_type_fields(), "yes" === wcbcf_public_params.maskedinput && (a(document.body).on("change", "#billing_country", function() {
                "BR" === a(this).val() ? b.maskBilling() : b.unmaskBilling()
            }), a(document.body).on("change", "#shipping_country", function() {
                "BR" === a(this).val() ? b.maskShipping() : b.unmaskShipping()
            }), this.maskGeneral()), "yes" === wcbcf_public_params.mailcheck && this.emailCheck(), a().select2 && a(".wc-ecfb-select").select2(), "BR" === a("#billing_country").val() && b.maskBilling()
        },
        country_to_state_changing: function() {
            a("#billing_state_field label").html(wcbcf_public_params.state + ' <abbr class="required" title="' + wcbcf_public_params.required + '">*</abbr>'), a("#billing_postcode_field").insertAfter("#billing_country_field"), a("#shipping_state_field").length && (a("#shipping_state_field label").html(wcbcf_public_params.state + ' <abbr class="required" title="' + wcbcf_public_params.required + '">*</abbr>'), a("#shipping_postcode_field").insertAfter("#shipping_country_field"))
        },
        person_type_fields: function() {
            "no" === wcbcf_public_params.only_brazil ? (a(".person-type-field label .required").remove(), a(".person-type-field").addClass("validate-required"), a(".person-type-field label").append(' <abbr class="required" title="' + wcbcf_public_params.required + '">*</abbr>')) : a("#billing_country").on("change", function() {
                "BR" === a(this).val() ? (a(".person-type-field label .required").remove(), a(".person-type-field").addClass("validate-required"), a(".person-type-field label").append(' <abbr class="required" title="' + wcbcf_public_params.required + '">*</abbr>')) : (a(".person-type-field").removeClass("validate-required"), a(".person-type-field label .required").remove())
            }).change(), "1" === wcbcf_public_params.person_type && a("#billing_persontype").on("change", function() {
                var b = a(this).val();
                a("#billing_cpf_field").hide(), a("#billing_rg_field").hide(), a("#billing_company_field").hide(), a("#billing_cnpj_field").hide(), a("#billing_ie_field").hide(), "1" === b && (a("#billing_cpf_field").show(), a("#billing_rg_field").show()), "2" === b && (a("#billing_company_field").show(), a("#billing_cnpj_field").show(), a("#billing_ie_field").show())
            }).change()
        },
        maskBilling: function() {
            b.maskPhone("#billing_phone, #billing_cellphone"), a("#billing_birthdate").mask("00/00/0000"), a("#billing_postcode").mask("00000-000"), a("#billing_phone, #billing_cellphone, #billing_birthdate, #billing_postcode").attr("type", "tel")
        },
        unmaskBilling: function() {
            a("#billing_phone, #billing_cellphone, #billing_birthdate, #billing_postcode").unmask().attr("type", "text")
        },
        maskShipping: function() {
            a("#shipping_postcode").mask("00000-000").attr("type", "tel")
        },
        unmaskShipping: function() {
            a("#shipping_postcode").unmask().attr("type", "text")
        },
        maskGeneral: function() {
            a("#billing_cpf, #credit-card-cpf").mask("000.000.000-00"), a("#billing_cnpj").mask("00.000.000/0000-00"), b.maskPhone("#credit-card-phone")
        },
        maskPhone: function(b) {
            var c = a(b),
                d = function(a) {
                    return 11 === a.replace(/\D/g, "").length ? "(00) 00000-0000" : "(00) 0000-00009"
                },
                e = {
                    onKeyPress: function(a, b, c, e) {
                        c.mask(d.apply({}, arguments), e)
                    }
                };
            c.mask(d, e)
        },
        emailCheck: function() {
            a("#wcbcf-mailsuggest").length < 1 && a("#billing_email").after('<div id="wcbcf-mailsuggest"></div>'), a("#billing_email").on("blur", function() {
                a("#wcbcf-mailsuggest").html(""), a(this).mailcheck({
                    suggested: function(b, c) {
                        a("#wcbcf-mailsuggest").html("Você quis dizer: " + c.full + "?")
                        alert("teste");
                    }
                })
            }), a("#wcbcf-mailsuggest").css({
                color: "#c00",
                fontSize: "small"
            })
        }
    };
    b.init()
});
```

O código acima funciona perfeitamente, gera as mascaras e faz validação em endereços de e-mail, no caso preciso colocar validação do CPF, para que ele certifique que é válido, a mascara é 999.999.999-99, o id do input é:

```
billing_cpf

<input type="tel" class="input-text " name="billing_cpf" id="billing_cpf" placeholder="" value="000.000.000-00" data-qa-id="CPF" required="required" maxlength="14">
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Você usa algum https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981189/jquery-validation-not-validate-multi-select-box-in-form?

Comment: Não uso multi select box, apenas :

<input type="tel" class="input-text " name="billing_cpf" id="billing_cpf" placeholder="" value="000.000.000-00" data-qa-id="CPF" required="required" maxlength="14">

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu vi do seu código, ele parece com o checkout do Magento.

Aqui tem um exemplo de como aplicar a máscara para o CPF

```js
/* global wcbcf_public_params */
/*jshint devel: true */
jQuery( function( $ ) {

 /**
  * Frontend actions
  */
 var wc_ecfb_frontend = {

  /**
   * Initialize frontend actions
   */
  init: function() {
   if ( '0' === wcbcf_public_params.sort_state_country ) {
    $( document.body ).on( 'country_to_state_changing', this.country_to_state_changing );
   }

   if ( '0' !== wcbcf_public_params.person_type ) {
    this.person_type_fields();
   }

   if ( 'yes' === wcbcf_public_params.maskedinput ) {
    if ( 'BR' === $( '#billing_country' ).val() ) {
     wc_ecfb_frontend.maskBilling();
    }
    $( document.body ).on( 'change', '#billing_country', function() {
     if ( 'BR' === $( this ).val() ) {
      wc_ecfb_frontend.maskBilling();
     } else {
      wc_ecfb_frontend.unmaskBilling();
     }
    });

    $( document.body ).on( 'change', '#shipping_country', function() {
     if ( 'BR' === $( this ).val() ) {
      wc_ecfb_frontend.maskShipping();
     } else {
      wc_ecfb_frontend.unmaskShipping();
     }
    });

    this.maskGeneral();
   }

   if ( 'yes' === wcbcf_public_params.mailcheck ) {
    this.emailCheck();
   }

   if ( 'yes' === wcbcf_public_params.addresscomplete ) {
    // Auto complete billing address.
    this.addressAutoComplete( 'billing' );
    this.addressAutoCompleteOnChange( 'billing' );

    // Auto complete shipping address.
    this.addressAutoComplete( 'shipping' );
    this.addressAutoCompleteOnChange( 'shipping' );
   }

   // Check if select2 exists.
   if ( $().select2 ) {
    $( '.wc-ecfb-select' ).select2();
   }
  },

  /**
   * Country to state changing.
   * Fix the fields order.
   */
  country_to_state_changing: function() {
   // Billing.
   $( '#billing_state_field label' ).html( wcbcf_public_params.state + ' <abbr class="required" title="' + wcbcf_public_params.required + '">*</abbr>' );
   $( '#billing_postcode_field' ).insertAfter( '#billing_country_field' );

   // Shipping.
   if ( $( '#shipping_state_field' ).length ) {
    $( '#shipping_state_field label' ).html( wcbcf_public_params.state + ' <abbr class="required" title="' + wcbcf_public_params.required + '">*</abbr>' );
    $( '#shipping_postcode_field' ).insertAfter( '#shipping_country_field' );
   }
  },

  person_type_fields: function() {
   // Required fields.
   if ( 'no' === wcbcf_public_params.only_brazil ) {
                $( '.person-type-field label .required' ).remove();
    $( '.person-type-field' ).addClass( 'validate-required' );
    $( '.person-type-field label' ).append( ' <abbr class="required" title="' + wcbcf_public_params.required + '">*</abbr>' );
   } else {
    $( '#billing_country' ).on( 'change', function () {
     var current = $( this ).val();

     if ( 'BR' === current ) {
                        $( '.person-type-field label .required' ).remove();
      $( '.person-type-field' ).addClass( 'validate-required' );
      $( '.person-type-field label' ).append( ' <abbr class="required" title="' + wcbcf_public_params.required + '">*</abbr>' );
     } else {
      $( '.person-type-field' ).removeClass( 'validate-required' );
      $( '.person-type-field label .required' ).remove();
     }
    }).change();
   }

   if ( '1' === wcbcf_public_params.person_type ) {
    $( '#billing_persontype' ).on( 'change', function () {
     var current = $( this ).val();

     $( '#billing_cpf_field' ).hide();
     $( '#billing_rg_field' ).hide();
     $( '#billing_company_field' ).hide();
     $( '#billing_cnpj_field' ).hide();
     $( '#billing_ie_field' ).hide();

     if ( '1' === current ) {
      $( '#billing_cpf_field' ).show();
      $( '#billing_rg_field' ).show();
     }

     if ( '2' === current ) {
      $( '#billing_company_field' ).show();
      $( '#billing_cnpj_field' ).show();
      $( '#billing_ie_field' ).show();
     }
    }).change();
   }
  },

  maskBilling: function() {
   wc_ecfb_frontend.maskPhone( '#billing_phone, #billing_cellphone' );
   $( '#billing_birthdate' ).mask( '00/00/0000' );
   $( '#billing_postcode' ).mask( '00000-000' );
   $( '#billing_phone, #billing_cellphone, #billing_birthdate, #billing_postcode' ).attr( 'type', 'tel' );
  },

  unmaskBilling: function() {
   $( '#billing_phone, #billing_cellphone, #billing_birthdate, #billing_postcode' ).unmask().attr( 'type', 'text' );
  },

  maskShipping: function() {
   $( '#shipping_postcode' ).mask( '00000-000' ).attr( 'type', 'tel' );
  },

  unmaskShipping: function() {
   $( '#shipping_postcode' ).unmask().attr( 'type', 'text' );
  },

  maskGeneral: function() {
   $( '#billing_cpf, #credit-card-cpf' ).mask( '000.000.000-00' );
   $( '#billing_cnpj' ).mask( '00.000.000/0000-00' );
   wc_ecfb_frontend.maskPhone( '#credit-card-phone' );
  },

  maskPhone: function(selector) {
   var $element = $(selector),
     MaskBehavior = function(val) {
      return val.replace(/\D/g, '').length === 11 ? '(00) 00000-0000' : '(00) 0000-00009';
     },
     maskOptions = {
      onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
       field.mask(MaskBehavior.apply({}, arguments), options);
      }
     };

   $element.mask(MaskBehavior, maskOptions);
  },

  emailCheck: function() {
   if ( $( '#wcbcf-mailsuggest' ).length < 1 ) {
    $( '#billing_email' ).after( '<div id="wcbcf-mailsuggest"></div>' );
   }

   $( '#billing_email' ).on( 'blur', function () {
    $( '#wcbcf-mailsuggest' ).html( '' );
    $( this ).mailcheck({
     suggested: function( element, suggestion ) {
      $( '#wcbcf-mailsuggest' ).html( 'Você quis dizer: ' + suggestion.full + '?' );
     }
    });
   });

   $( '#wcbcf-mailsuggest' ).css({
    color: '#c00',
    fontSize: 'small'
   });
  },

  addressAutoComplete: function( field ) {
   // Checks with *_postcode field exist.
   if ( $( '#' + field + '_postcode' ).length ) {

    // Valid CEP.
    var cep       = $( '#' + field + '_postcode' ).val().replace( '.', '' ).replace( '-', '' ),
     country   = $( '#' + field + '_country' ).val(),
     address_1 = $( '#' + field + '_address_1' ).val();

    // Check country is BR.
    if ( cep !== '' && 8 === cep.length && 'BR' === country && 0 === address_1.length ) {

     // Gets the address.
     $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '//correiosapi.apphb.com/cep/' + cep,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      crossDomain: true,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function ( address ) {

       // Address.
       if ( '' !== address.tipoDeLogradouro ) {
        $( '#' + field + '_address_1' ).val( address.tipoDeLogradouro + ' ' + address.logradouro ).change();
       } else {
        $( '#' + field + '_address_1' ).val( address.logradouro ).change();
       }

       // Neighborhood.
       $( '#' + field + '_neighborhood' ).val( address.bairro ).change();

       // City.
       $( '#' + field + '_city' ).val( address.cidade ).change();

       // State.
       $( '#' + field + '_state option:selected' ).attr( 'selected', false ).change();
       $( '#' + field + '_state option[value="' + address.estado + '"]' ).attr( 'selected', 'selected' ).change();

       // Chosen support.
       $( '#' + field + '_state' ).trigger( 'liszt:updated' ).trigger( 'chosen:updated' );
      }
     });
    }
   }
  },

  addressAutoCompleteOnChange: function( field ) {
   $( document.body ).on( 'blur', '#' + field + '_postcode', function() {
    wc_ecfb_frontend.addressAutoComplete( field );
   });
  }
 };

 wc_ecfb_frontend.init();
});
```

Comment: Legal, porém o meu código já aplica a mascara, oque eu realmente quero é que verifica se o CPF é válido ou inválido, que o código faça esta checagem.